# Private chat conversation only with rooms in Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I want to have a private conversation with **only** two people.

Is it fine if I only use the [rooms](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#Default-room) feature for it in Socket.IO? 
Or is there a better way of doing a 2 people conversation in socket.io?

Im using NodeJS for the backend

That is my client:

```js
var socket = io.connect('http://ip:port');

socket.emit('subscribe', conversation_id);

socket.emit('send message', {
    room: conversation_id,
    message: "Some message"
});

socket.on('conversation private post', function(data) {
    //display data.message
});
```

and this is my server:

```js
socket.on('subscribe', function(room) {
    console.log('joining room', room);
    socket.join(room);
});

socket.on('send message', function(data) {
    console.log('sending room post', data.room);
    socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('conversation private post', {
        message: data.message
    });
});
```